# Deriving spring oscilation period

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

We have a spring attached to a wall and at the other part an object on a frictionless surface.
I tried to calculate the spring oscilation period. I used the conservation of energy and kinematics equations for the average acceleration. $$\frac{1}{2}kA^2 = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 \Rightarrow v^2=k\frac{A^2}{m}$$
$$v^2=2aA+v_0^2=2aA \Rightarrow \frac{kA^2}{m}=2aA \Rightarrow a= \frac{kA}{2m}$$
$$v=at \Rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{kA^2}{m}}=\frac{kA}{2m} t \Rightarrow t= 2 \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}.$$

This only the motion from the amplitude to the $x=0$ position. The forward 3 parts are the same because the kinetic energy is constantly transformed into elastic potential. 
$$T=4t=8 \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$$
I used the kinematics equations for some average acceleration of out varrying acceleration.
The formula said $T=2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$. $\pi$ doesn't equal 4.

Can anybody explain how to derive the formula ?

Comment: What are "kinematics equations"? Also, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) deals with the simple harmonic oscillator perfectly.

Comment: Aghh, you should use [math formatting](http://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your derivation. Your main mistake is using formulae that assume the acceleration of the spring is constant (it is not). In one dimensional systems with nonuniform acceleration, we have

$$
v(t) = v_0 + \int_{t_0}^t a(t)dt .
$$

Furthermore, the $v^2 = v_0^2 + 2a \Delta x$ no longer works for nonuniform accelerations either. Here is how to derive the oscillation period of a spring. First, consider a reference frame where x is the displacement of the spring. We know that the force on the spring is $F_{spring} = -kx$, so

$$
F_{net} = -kx = ma .
$$

Now let's substitute the acceleration for $a = d^2x/dt^2$ and rearrange the terms on one side, so

$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \frac{k}{m}x = 0 .
$$

A well-known result from differential equations theory is that any differential equation like

$$
\frac{d^2g}{dt^2} + \omega^2g = 0
$$

has solutions of the form

$$
g(t) = Acos(\omega t) + Bsin(\omega t)
$$

where A and B are arbitrary constants depending on initial values of the system. Thus, comparing this result with our differential equation from the spring yields an angular oscillation frequency of

$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{x}}.$$

and a frequency of

$$f = \frac{\omega}{2 \pi} = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\sqrt{\frac{k}{x}}.$$

We can do even better than this! Suppose $x_0$ is the initial displacement and $v_0$ is the object's initial velocity (we're assuming the spring is a uniform body). Let's take a look at the solution and its derivative at $t = 0$.

$$
x(0) = x_0 = Acos(0) + Bsin(0) = A
$$

and

$$
v(0) = v_0 = - \omega A sin(0) + \omega B cos(0)  = \omega B
$$

Thus, the complete solution for a Hookian spring with an initial displacement $x_0$ and an initial velocity $v_0$ is

$$
x(t) = x_0 cos\sqrt{k/m} t) + v_0 \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}} sin(\sqrt{k/m} t)
$$

Comment: Maybe a little bit too much detail for homework.

Comment: Good point, but I think that any proper physics textbook would derive this anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mass moving under the influence of a simple massless spring. The equations of motion are $F = -k x = m a$. These can be solved using direct integration.

$$ \begin{aligned} 
    a =\frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}  & = -\frac{k}{m} x \\
    \int \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t}  \, {\rm d}x & = - \int \frac{k}{m} x \,{\rm d} x \\
    \int  v \, {\rm d}v & = - \int \frac{k}{m} x \,{\rm d} x \\
    \frac{1}{2} v^2 - \frac{1}{2} v_0^2 & = - \int \frac{k}{m} x \,{\rm d} x \\
     v &= \pm \sqrt{v_0^2-\frac{k}{m} x^2 }
\end{aligned} $$

$$ \begin{aligned}
    t & =\int \frac{1}{v}\,{\rm d} x \\
      & =\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}} \sin^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} \frac{x}{v_0} \right) \\
    x & = \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}} v_0 \sin\left( \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t \right)
\end{aligned}$$

From which the frequency is obviously $f = \frac{ \omega}{2\pi} = \frac{\sqrt{k}}{2\pi \sqrt{m}}$